# Linux: how do I turn a text file into a variable that is a list of strings?

Tags: linux

I used the split command to generate the files: fileaa .. fileaz and fileba ... filebd. I have written these names to the file *filenames.list.txt* that looks like this:

```
fileaa fileab fileac filead fileae fileaf fileag fileah fileai fileaj fileak fileal fileam filean fileao fileap fileaq filear fileas fileat fileau fileav fileaw fileax fileay fileaz fileba filebb filebc filebd
```

I want to write this list from the text file into a variable in the following script:

```
file='fileaa fileab fileac filead fileae fileaf fileag fileah fileai fileaj fileak fileal fileam filean fileao fileap fileaq filear fileas fileat fileau fileav fileaw fileax fileay fileaz fileba filebb filebc filebd'


for k in {1..30}
do
cat header$k.txt $file > run_mash$k.sh
done
```

The final result that I want is the following

```
cat header1.txt fileaa > run_mash1.sh
cat header2.txt fileab > run_mash2.sh
.
.
cat header26.txt fileaz > run_mash26.sh
cat header27.txt fileba > run_mash27.sh
.
.
cat header30.txt filebd > run_mash30.sh
```

Answer (score 0):

I got it working:
File list: `/tmp/listfiles.txt`

```
~ > cat /tmp/listfiles.txt                                                                                                                                      at 14:35:53
fileaa fileab fileac filead fileae fileaf fileag fileah fileai fileaj fileak fileal fileam filean fileao fileap fileaq filear fileas fileat fileau fileav fileaw fileax fileay fileaz fileba filebb filebc filebd
```

Script: `/tmp/script.sh`

```
~ > cat /tmp/script.sh                                                                                                                                          at 14:35:56
#!/bin/bash

file=`cat /tmp/listfiles.txt`

IDX=1
for i in $file
do
  echo "cat header${IDX}.txt $i > run_mash${IDX}.sh"
  ((IDX++))
done
```

Example execution:

```
~ > bash /tmp/script.sh                                                                                                                                     INT at 14:36:56
cat header1.txt fileaa > run_mash1.sh
cat header2.txt fileab > run_mash2.sh
cat header3.txt fileac > run_mash3.sh
cat header4.txt filead > run_mash4.sh
cat header5.txt fileae > run_mash5.sh
cat header6.txt fileaf > run_mash6.sh
cat header7.txt fileag > run_mash7.sh
cat header8.txt fileah > run_mash8.sh
cat header9.txt fileai > run_mash9.sh
cat header10.txt fileaj > run_mash10.sh
cat header11.txt fileak > run_mash11.sh
cat header12.txt fileal > run_mash12.sh
cat header13.txt fileam > run_mash13.sh
cat header14.txt filean > run_mash14.sh
cat header15.txt fileao > run_mash15.sh
cat header16.txt fileap > run_mash16.sh
cat header17.txt fileaq > run_mash17.sh
cat header18.txt filear > run_mash18.sh
cat header19.txt fileas > run_mash19.sh
cat header20.txt fileat > run_mash20.sh
cat header21.txt fileau > run_mash21.sh
cat header22.txt fileav > run_mash22.sh
cat header23.txt fileaw > run_mash23.sh
cat header24.txt fileax > run_mash24.sh
cat header25.txt fileay > run_mash25.sh
cat header26.txt fileaz > run_mash26.sh
cat header27.txt fileba > run_mash27.sh
cat header28.txt filebb > run_mash28.sh
cat header29.txt filebc > run_mash29.sh
cat header30.txt filebd > run_mash30.sh
```

Just remove the echo inside the script to make the script execute all the `cat` commands`.|
Regards.